# Rows to column conversion in unix

Tags: unix

I have data in a unix file in the following format, need to convert as below.

***FROM***

```
ABC: XYZ_RMP1(1),UVW_RMP1(1)
DEF: UVW_RMP1(2),MNS_ABT2(3),AMO_KYZ3(
GHI: AMO_KYZ3(1),NPO_ABT1(4)
JKL: HJY_RST4(1),TSU_RMP1(5),FBT_MUS6(3)
```

***TO***

```
ABC_XYZ_RMP1
ABC_UVW_RMP1
DEF_UVW_RMP1
DEF_MNS_ABT2
DEF_AMO_KYZ3
GHI_AMO_KYZ3
GHI_NPO_ABT1
JKL_HJY_RST4
JKL_TSU_RMP1
JKL_FBT_MUS6
```

i tried the below commands

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\n",$i}'  file >> file1
sed 's|[:(),]||g' file1  >> file2
sed 's/.$//' b.txt file2 >> file3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
 sed 's/,/ /g' input | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s %s\n",$1,$i}' | sed 's/: /_/;s/(.*)//g' > output
```

Comment: output  is    ABC_XYZ_RMP1    ABC_XYZ_RMP1  but  i am looking for   ABC_XYZ_RMP1    ABC_UVW_RMP1

Comment: Don't see that, output is like specified in the question.

Comment: my bad however the following worked for me   sed 's/:/: /g' a.txt | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s %s\n",$1,$i}' | sed 's/: /_/;s/(.*)//g'

Comment: So I suggest you accept the answer and we close the question.